# CMake ExternalData custom fetch script

Tags: c++, cmake, post-build

**Introduction**

I have a project with a "tests" target that requires some extracted assets from a remote source to be present in the build tree at run-time. At present I have used [ExternalData](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/ExternalData.html) to, at build time, retrieve a zipped file from a remote url and place it into the build tree.

`/tests/CMakeLists.txt` :

```
include(ExternalData)
set(ExternalData_URL_TEMPLATES "https://data.com/path/samples.zip")

# [...]

ExternalData_Add_Test(MyData
   NAME MyTest
   COMMAND MyProjectTests DATA{samples.zip})
ExternalData_Add_Target(MyData)
```

(In the source tree I have a file `/tests/samples.zip.md5` which contains the md5 of the archive.)

**Question**

I would like to extract this archive after it is retrieved. From reading the CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/ExternalData.html#variable:ExternalData_CUSTOM_SCRIPT_%3Ckey%3E) there appears to be a way to use a custom fetch script when retrieving from a remote.

The documentation does not show an example of a custom fetch script. It mentions that the file(DOWNLOAD) command is used normally, but it does not show explicitly how its *default behaviour* could be replicated by a custom fetch script.

I wish to implement and use a custom fetch script that replicates ExternalData's default behaviour, so that I can add a [file(ARCHIVE_EXTRACT)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command to extract the archive.

(I would also like to know whether extracting downloaded files should be a responsibility of a custom fetch script, and if not, where the best place is to put this is, given that the asset is only downloaded at build time).

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to replicate the default behaviour of ExternalData's fetch script. However, using `add_custom_command()`, I have extracted the test assets as a `POST_BUILD` step.

Appending to `/tests/CMakeLists.txt` :

```
set(ASSETS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${ASSETS_DIRECTORY})
set(ExternalData_BINARY_ROOT ${ASSETS_DIRECTORY})

add_custom_command(TARGET waveioTests
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND 
                   dir & 
                   echo "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy samples.tar ${ASSETS_DIRECTORY}/samples.tar" & 
                   ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy samples.tar ${ASSETS_DIRECTORY}/samples.tar & 
                   ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir ${ASSETS_DIRECTORY} tar vxf samples.tar
                   COMMENT "Extracting test assets...")
```